# Module build failed: @import '../../node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/toolbar';

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting this error when I try to run an app on my machine

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed: 
@import '../../node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/toolbar';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: ../../node_modules/@angular/material/toolbar/toolbar.
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: have you installed the toolbar?

Comment: yes, I tried ```npm install @material/toolbar``` and I still get the same error

Comment: have you checked if you have entered the right path?

Comment: in @angular/material/toolbar I have the files: _toolbar-theme.scss, index.d.ts, index.metadata.json, package.json, public-api.d.ts, toolbar-module.d.ts and toolbar.d.ts. Which one should I choose?

Comment: can you add the file where you imported toolbar

Comment: ```import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';                          @NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, MatToolbarModule],                                          })```